# Is UNIQUE key column have the same index on a table , can i remove that indexing key or not

Tags: mysql, sql

Have following table

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `papers` (
     `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `version` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
     `paper_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      UNIQUE KEY `paper_name_un` (`paper_name`),
      KEY `paper_names_idx` (`paper_name`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In above table we have an unique key for paper_name column, and indexing key for same column.
can we remove that indexing key (i.e paper_names_idx).?
 if we  remove that indexing key, then unique key it self used for indexing or not..? 
 is  UNIQUE key automatically create an INDEX on the columns?

Comment: The `KEY` statement is redundant.  You can remove it.

Comment: it also won't run due to lack of a PK that is required for an AI column. That fixed, a `show indexes from papers;` will show the duped up index